# Using Google Analytics with multiple websites on the same domain name

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a hotspot software. This software is used by multiple clients. Individual client page design is determined based on the initial GET parameters, e.g.

- http://wifi.com/?client=1 will redirect user to http://wifi.com/ and will show pages for the client #1,
- http://wifi.com/?client=2 will redirect user to http://wifi.com/ and will show pages for the client #2.

How to track:

- Analytics Information for all of the clients aggregated
- Analytics Information for individual client

Answer (score 0):

I was considering two options, that I'd like to share:

1. Is to have multiple tracking codes. One for every client and one generic.
2. Is to use [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables). More precisely, to set `session-level` slot 1 variable to `client-id`.

Is either of these solutions valid?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use Universal Analytics you could use the [`cookieName`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#configure) parameter to use different cookies based on the client whose pages are shown.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'cookieName': '_ga_client1'
});
```

This means you have completely separate tracking cookies and therefor visitors and sessions for every client.

At the same time you could use a classic Analytics tracker to track aggregate data.